# How to check my phone hardware specs on Android terminal emulator

Tags: terminal, command-line

I was wondering if there is a command to check the hardware specs of my phone. I just installed the Android terminal emulator. I've tried the 'lshw' but it does not work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can enter `getprop` to get info about device. Or, you can do `cat /system/build.prop`

If you've root access then you can enter `su` and then  `dumpsys | less` to get the name of the services which can give more info about some specific things such as battery. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201659/whats-the-android-adb-shell-dumpsys-tool-and-what-are-its-benefits) to know more.

On a non-rooted device, you can do `adb shell dumpsys | less` provided that [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) is running in wireless mode and your device is connected locally in loopback mode. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623727) for more info.

Comment: There are some bits and pieces under `/dev`, `/proc` and `/sys` but I can't get a hold on a central point like `lshw`.

Comment: And `dumpstate` has too many things to figure out.